# Discord.js How to change verification level

Tags: discord, discord.js

I want to change verification level in my discord server using with discord.js . Can you help me how can i do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to interpret your question more specifically. How do you want to do this? A command when starting a bot, when connecting to a server?

With `on message` trigger you can do this as follow.

```
client.on('message', message => {
  if (message.content.startsWith('!changeverlvl') {
    message.guild.setVerificationLevel(1).then(g => {
        message.reply(`Updated guild verification level to ${g.verificationLevel}`)
    }).catch(console.error)
  }
});
```